# ngFor iterating through inside array object array using angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have this JSON

[

```
        {
            Id: "14",
            Title: "HR Europe",
            Description: "HR Europe",
            Color: "3B23FF",
            Contents: [
                {
                    Id: "15",
                    Title: "W.I.D.E Experience",
                    Description: "Discover our Value!",
                    Date: new Date('2019-12-02'),
                    Type: "content",
                  },
                {
                    Id: "17",
                    Title: Experience",
                    Description: "Discover our Value!",
                    Date: new Date('2019-12-02'),
                    Type: "content",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Id: "12",
            Title: "Company",
            Description: "Company",
            Color: "4FFF26",
            Contents: [
                {
                    Id: "13",
                    Title: "CEO &amp; Presidents Environmental Message",
                    Description: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    Date: new Date('2020-02-13'),
                    Type: "content",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Id: "8",
            Title: "Engine",
            Description: "Engine",
            Color: "FF4F0C",
            Contents: [
                {
                    Id: "10",
                    Title: "Pre Bunker Training",
                    Description: "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
                    Date: new Date('2019-12-02'),
                    Type: "content",
                   },
                {
                    Id: "11",
                    Title: "Exhaust Gas Cleaning System pH-Sensor cleaning",
                    Description: "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu",
                    Date: new Date('2019-12-02'),
                    Type: "content",

                }
            ]
```

I want to show this title `Title: "CEO &amp; Presidents Environmental Message"` `{{item?.Contents.Title}}` but I used not correct and show

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
> 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Can you share with me any idea how to use `*ngFor` in this part?

Comment: `Contents` property is an array. Either access specific elements directly `{{item?.Contents[0].Title}}` or use a nested `*ngFor`.

Comment: I want to see all Contents, not only `Contents[0]`

Comment: You could use a nested `*ngFor`.

Comment: Yes, but How can I use it?

Comment: Can you add further code related to this? how are you using the JSON file? are you parsing it as an object before using it in the html? 

Maybe add the component code too (.html and .ts).

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example of what you're asking, basically it uses two *ngFor to go through the data.

You need a first ngFor to iterate the array of items you provided.

Then a second ngFor to iterate the array of Contents for each item iterated above.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div *ngFor="let content of item.Contents">
    {{content.Title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uv9ydx) i've made that shows both iterations.

I advice you to check Angular documentation about [structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) (ngIf,ngFor,...).